# Fontawesome is not displayed correctly on laravel when using xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, serve

There seems to be a difference between using `xampp` and `PHP's built-in development server`. When I use `php artisan serve` on my `laravel environment`, all icons from `fontawesome` are displayed correctly.

But when I use `xampp`, all icons look like [squares with little numbers in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijFYJ.jpg).

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to define the `public path` in `laravel mix`, because `xampp` use another root-path then `php artisan serve`.

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/index.php     //xampp
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php                 //serve
```

So I had to add to my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your XAMPP and serving by php is in ports: 80 on xampp and 8000 on php artisan serve. 
There are two ways to fix it:

1) set port to 80 while `php artisan serve --port 80`

2) set proper app url in envireonment (`.env`) file: APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

Comment: When I use xampp, `fontawesome` does not work. If I use `php artisan serve` (no matter which port), `fontawesome` works perfectly. Why is that?

Comment: ok, clear, thx. You can find fontawesome files loading response in your network tab (Chrome, Frefox etc). Please just look at network loads, find fontawesome files and see what happens in response. Looks like paths are not correct and files are not loading. When you load app via `app serve` - everything is configured from the box, but when via xampp - you need to take care about paths in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Comment: Also one of the best ways to debug this issue - to load fontawesome file via cdn in `head` block : <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">